# Regex - Match URLs except an isolated case

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern which was made to match attempts of URLs advertisement.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?
(\.|\(\.\)|dot|\(dot\)|-|;|:|,)\s
(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me)\b
```

I also made this formula detect attempts of outsmarting the protection such as:

```
www-google-com or google-com (using '-' instead of '.')
```

### The Problem

I got reported that, in the Portuguese language, words like

> "ganhou-me" or "fugiu-me"

are valid and still getting caught by the protection. The hyphen is used together with "me" domain and causing the confusion.

I'm trying to find a way to exclude that particular case from the expression but:

- Still be able to detect attempts like: google.me or google;me
- But ignore attempts like: google-me or ganhou-me

I thought about removing the "me" from the main expression and add a disjunction that included that particular case, but that sounds like the hardest solution?

Comment: Sounds like a tough problem. I'm not sure you'd like to maintain a curated list of Portuguese words like `"ganhou-me"` and `"fugiu-me"` because I can see that becoming unwieldy. Seems like a spam vs. ham problem, which is sometimes better suited for Machine Learning unfortunately. Otherwise you can try hacking it with either some whitelisted Portuguese words...

Comment: Yes, I can also try whitelisting some words. But since, the worst recurring problem is this one, I was trying to find out if there's an easy fix for the expression.

Comment: Your question as phrased, and per wcarrol comment, implies you want a whitelist/blacklist combination (exclude these, except for those). That also sounds like a better solution than a disjunction in the regex. Presumably you could set up language-dependent whitelists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all -me addresses to not be matched and your language supports negative Look-behind you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?(\.|\(\.\)|dot|\(dot\)|-|;|:|,)\s?(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|(?<!-)me)\b` or here is a Look-ahead version `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?(\.|\(\.\)|dot|\(dot\)|-(?!me)|;|:|,)\s?(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me)\b`.

This works by using `(?<!-)` to check there is a - before 'me' when matching in the first one or uses this `-(?!me)` to check there is an 'me' after the - in the second one.

Here is it working in a java-script example. Note- I used the second version as java-script does not support Look-behind.

```js
 var value = "www.google.com www.google;me www.google-me";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\s?(\\.|\\(\\.\\)|dot|\\(dot\\)|-(?!me)|;|:|,)\\s?(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me)\\b", "g")
);
document.writeln(matches);
```

Of course it might be better to use a white list (suggested in comments above) as this is very general.